Rspress import monorepo package in docs page
I am just getting started with Rspress and would like to create a documentation site for my monorepo packages.
What I have so far is this structure
/project-root
  /docs
    index.mdx
    /packages
      alpha.mdx
      omega.mdx
  /packages
    /alpha
      beta.ts
    /omega
      omicron.ts

I would like to include packages/alpha/beta.ts in /docs/packages/alpha.mdx as a module (to offer an in-page playground) and as source (possibly, to extract the docblock content).
I have not been successful in figuring out the config needed to enable this. I'd rather like to avoid symlinking everything in /packages inside of /docs as that just feels like a hack.
